# Influxdb 2.0 running in K8s gets data lost every time Statefulset pod is scaled down or rescheduled

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, amazon-eks, influxdb-2

I have deployed **Influxdb 2.0.0** as Statefulset with EBS volume persistence. I've noticed that, if for some reason, pod gets rescheduled to other node or even if we scale down statefulset pod replicas = 0 and then scale up, the effect would be the same on persisted data: they will be lost.

Initially, in case of pod that gets rescheduled to other node, I would thought the problem is with EBS volume, it doesn't get unmounted and them mounted to another node where pod replica is running but that is NOT the case. EBS volume is present, same pv/pvc exists, but data is lost.

To figure out what might be the problem, I've purposely done influxdb setup and added data and then did this:

```
kubectl scale statefulsets influxdb --replicas=0
...
kubectl scale statefulsets influxdb --replicas=1
```

The effect was the same just like when influxdb pod got rescheduled. Data was lost.

Any specific reason why would something like that happen?

My environment:
I'm using EKS k8s environment with **1.15** k8s version of control plane/workers.

Comment: Without you posting the helm chart you used, or your StatefulSet descriptors, or knowing **anything** about your setup, there is no way in the world for anyone to possibly help you

Comment: What is your persistent volume [reclaiming](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaiming)?

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, the problem was due to the big changes that happened between influxdb 1.x and 2.0.0 beta version in terms on where the actual data is persisted.

In 1.x version, data was persisted in:

```
/var/lib/influxdb
```

while on the 2.x version, data is persisted, by default, on:

```
/root/.influxdbv2
```

My EBS volume was mounted on the 1.x version location and with every restart of the pod (either caused by scaling down or by scheduling to other node), EBS volume was regularly attached but on the wrong location. That was the reason why there was no data.

Also, one difference that I see is that configuration params cannot be provided for 2.x version via configuration file (like it was on 1.x where I had configuration file mounted into the container as configmap). We have to provide additional configuration params inline. This link explains how: https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/reference/config-options/

At the end this is the working version of Statefulset:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: influxdb
  name: influxdb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: influxdb
  serviceName: influxdb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: influxdb
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: quay.io/influxdb/influxdb:2.0.0-beta
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: api
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          name: influxdb
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9999
              name: api
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: api
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "800m"
              memory: 1200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 256Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /root/.influxdbv2
              name: influxdb-data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: influxdb-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 20Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
```

Comment: What do you mean " provide additional configuration params inline." ? CLI command or environment variables ?